# Issue opening word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

Currently we have a .dot/.dat files which have template loaded and user when selects for a particular document we use the template generate a word document store it in temp location and display to user. When we are trying to access these documents we are getting an error as "Could not open macro storage.". I enabled macros on word document, and gave full read write permissions to user on template location on server. Nothing is fixing any ideas or pointers if anyone as came across this kind of similar issue. This is a windows desktop application.